# Pass gallery image data from Activity to DialogPreferences

Tags: android, image, android-fragments

I have created one Settings Activity. In which I there are many fragments. 
One of them has Logo settings (DialogPreferences), in which I need to select image from the gallery and needs to display that image into ImageView of the DialogPreferences.

Now, I am getting Gallery image in onActivityResult of the Settings activity. However, I need that image data into Configuration(Fragment)-> LogoPreferences (DialogPreferences).

So, my question is, how can I get image data from onActivityResult (of Activity) to LogoPreferences( that is DialogPreference and it is inside Configuration fragment).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `Bitmap` image that you get from `onActivityResult()` to a *ByteArray*, and then convert the array back to your `LogoPreferences` activity (or whichever activity you want the data to go to). Here is something you could do:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Check to see the result is from the activity you are targeting
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            Log.i("Image Path", selectedImage.getPath());

            // Convert bitmap to byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored if PNG*/, bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putByteArray("byteArray", bitmapdata);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogoPreferences.class);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then to decode that byte array in the `LogoPreferences` activity, you could do this:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        // Optionally set the Bitmap to an ImageView
        ImageView imv = new ImageView(this);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
```

Hope it helps!